# How to create a custom safe mode option

Tags: windows, windows-registry, safe-mode, bcdedit, ntldr

I want to create a custom safe mode option (like Minimal and Network).
I began by going to the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot
```

and made a new key called `ExtS` (for "Extended Services").
I then copied all of the entries from `Network` to `ExtS` (as a base) and added some more.  So far, so good.
Then, I tried to make it the default Safe Mode option by running `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot ExtS`, and got the fallowing error message:

> The integer data is not valid as specified.
> Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
> The parameter is incorrect.

Since `Minimal` and `Network` work, I am suspecting there is some kind of list of accepted values and corresponding integers for them.

Comment: Have you tried bcdedit /? /set

Comment: I tried to point out the 'strange' syntax of the help switch, but looking through the help myself it's not easy to see where you can find more info on safeboot beyond minimal/network/etc.

Comment: I do not understand the part with the reference to ExtU, or did you mean ExtS ? have you tried to modify the Network (for instance) branch itself - making it 'your own' and then run 'Network'? After making a backup of course. What are the primary keys you want to change?

Comment: @reben, I meant I was making my own key called `ExtU`, and yes I have, I just really don’t want to break safe mode.  As [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1361370/windows-is-stuck-in-safe-mode) explains, I am spending significent time in safe mode and I want to make it less of a minimal environment.

Comment: Try to check the link below if it is useful for you:https://blog.didierstevens.com/2007/03/26/playing-with-safe-mode/